# How do I gauge the quality of battery spot welds?

Tags: power-electronics, lithium-ion

I've built a DIY spot welder for 18650 battery packs. It works fine, but I'm not sure how to evaluate the resulting welds. Specifically I would like to identify when the weld energy is too low or too high.

Higher energies *stick better*, but certainly at some point it will damage the cells. I'm not able to find any documentation from a trustworthy source on how to judge.

My setup does not measure the current unfortunately so I can't calculate the Joules delivered, but if that's critical I can find a way to measure it.

I'm using 0.15mm pure nickel strip, and welding with a 12Ah 50C 3S drone battery if it matters.

Comment: The best way to check if you’ve damaged a cell is to measure the cell impedance before and after the weld

Comment: One test of spot welds is the peel test. If you need to test if you've breached the cell casing you could use one of the techniques used for watch waterproofing testing. Neither of these is on-topic here. You should never be putting current through the cell in the welding process, of course, so you can't damage the cell unless you damage the casing.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany You don't think I could thermally damage the jellyroll by heating the case red hot for some milliseconds? I don't think I'm anywhere close to burning through.

Comment: Does it look like the welds you see on professional batteries?  Are you able to tear it off or does it hold tight???

Comment: @Drew No I don't think so, but I wouldn't want to underestimate you. If the weld takes place in << 1 second I think it would be fine. The metal should only get hot at the interface not over a wide area.

Comment: I was hoping to find some official guidelines or something. There's tons of advice out there but it's all just one guy saying "make it like this" with no citation or engineering justification.